# CFileFind::FindFile and network paths

Tags: networking, path, cfilefind

I have a dll that opens a file for processing. It attempts to find the file with FindFile() function. I also have a service that calls the dll and here is the problem - when the path to the file is a network path, FindFile() fails to find it but only when called from the service, if I call it directly from my application it finds the file. I'm sure the FindFile() function gets the same parameters in both cases as I write a log file with it. Parameter looks like this:
"\SERVER\SERVER_USERS\USERX\TEST.TXT"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is  6 months after the question, but I figured I'd answer it anyway ... Usually, it is a permissions thing. If the service does not have access to the network folder, then it won't find anything. Many services run as a local system account by default, and that account doesn't have built-in access to network files. So try making sure the service is running as an account that has access to the network folder in question.